# How to use Protobuf and JSON API simultaneously on SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My project only had Protobuf APIs, but now it has to provide JSON APIs, too.

`protobufHttpMessageConverter` was applied to all controllers by configuration.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class APIConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    fun protobufHttpMessageConverter(): ProtobufHttpMessageConverter {
        val converter = ProtobufHttpMessageConverter()
        converter.defaultCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        return converter
    }
}
```

But now it should be applied to some controllers that provide Protobuf APIs, and should not be applied to other controllers that provide JSON APIs.

Does SpringBoot have that kind of flexibility?

Comment: I believe that’s what MIME types are for. Your use case is no different than serving XML and JSON to different customers.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Do you mean that protobufHttpMessageConverter doesn't work when MIME is set to Controller endpoint function?

Comment: I’d think so if you designate your controllers to handle different types.